# How to run HoneyComb emulator faster on Windows?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is there any way to get the emulator work normally ?
Its still very slow and useless, I tried adjusting the cache size and Ram.
My system configuration is quite good, are there any tips and hints to speed up the avd ?

Comment: I have a crappy $300 toshiba laptop with 2GB RAM and the HoneyComb emulator runs fine on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much you can do, but Al Sutton lays out some things that can help a bit.
http://blog.alsutton.com/2011/01/27/the-android-honeycomb-preview-emulator/

For serious development, you'll need a Honeycomb tablet.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it improves very soon. Just saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814992/honeycomb-android-emulator-is-dog-slow-will-it-get-manageable-before-the-offici and also developer site states this would be improved, so nothing more can we do.

Comment: Another option is http://www.deviceanywhere.com/ who have devices you can run stuff on remotely - it'd a paid service though.

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard the many complaints about how slow the Honeycomb emulator is. And indeed, the Android emulators have long been slow. Certainly slower than most phones. But Honeycomb is slower, so much so, that even Google engineers have admitted it makes more sense to develop testing on a real tablet.

Now my experience has been a little surprising: on my 1.6(?)GHz Pentium with 4G of memory running Win7, I have been surprised at how fast it runs. That is, I was prepared for the worse, yet found the response time to taps surprisingly reasonable.

That said, it is still noticeably slower than the 2.2 emulator. But not as slow as the real hardware we had to suffer with in the 80s;)

Finally, not only the emulator, but the whole SDK (including that memory hog Eclipse) become a LOT more usable when you have at least 3.5G of memory available. This means a 4G stick. When I was trying to run the 1.6 SDK under Linux with only 2G, it was frustrating how often Eclipse locked up. But with 4G, it is fine. So upgrade your memory to at least 4G before you worry about other measures, such as faster CPU.